# How should I save data imported from API through R

Tags: r, hive, hdfs

I have imported data from Google analytics API and I have now multiple data frames in my script. Now, I would like to store it so that later I can specify these as data location for hive external tables. (hive tables are just like sql tables with schema , just that these can source data from flat files).

Let's say I have df1 , df2....df 30.

What should be the next step to store this data in HDFS? Should I create a file per dataframe or may be something else?

Comment: write.csv(df1,file="df1.csv"); write.csv(df2,file="df2.csv"); write.csv(df30,file="df30.csv") This writes the data frames to R's working directory as .csv files (use getwd() to learn your R's working directory). You can then retrieve these .csv files anytime you wish.

Comment: Simran, do you want the imported data to be a part of your package you are creating? If so, the procedure is totally different. Please specify whether **1** "the imported data will be accesible from your package directly" or **2** "the imported data will be accessed later through a `read.csv` procedure where the stored .csv is somewhere in your PC"

Comment: @ErdoganCEVHER: The imported data has to be available in HDFS only which is the file system in hadoop. For that matter, I just need to pass in the location and write the data in required directory